# jQuery code difference

Tags: jquery

Let me start by saying that I'm not a JavaScript programer or a jQuery guru by any means, I'm actually just starting with jQuery.

I have the two following jQuery codes:

```
$('.tipTrigger').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').prev('.tipText').stop(true, true).fadeToggle('fast'); 
});
```

and

```
if ($(".tooltip-container").length > 0){        
    $('.tipTrigger').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active').prev('.tipText').stop(true, true).fadeToggle('fast'); 
    });
}
```

Several questions I have about this:

1. What is basically the difference between the two codes above?
2. What is the meaning of `if ($(".tooltip-container").length > 0){`?
3. Is there a benefit to using the above `if`?
4. What's more 'efficient' from a developer's stand point? (that is IF something so small would have a considerable performance impact in any way)

Any other comments/help with this simple comparison would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What is basically the difference between the two codes above?

  > The second will only set the hover function if there is an element on the page with the class 'tooltip-container'
- What is the meaning of if '($(".tooltip-container").length > 0){'?

  > Simple if statement to test if element having class `tooltip-container` exist on document
- Is there a benefit to using the above `if`?

  > In short, in this case, not really, since the .hover wont be asigned unless an element having class`tipTrigger` exist anyway.  Also this could cause performance issues since it only checks to see if one `tooltip-container` element exist.  If this is a check to ensure `tipTrigger` is "inside" said container, it will fail in that as soon as one element with `tooltip-container` is found, ALL elements with `tipTrigger` will be asigned hover function and this MAY BE undesired.
- What's more 'efficient' from a developer's stand point? (that is IF something so small would have a considerable performance impact in any way)

  > If you must check to make sure that only `tipTrigger` elements inside `tooltip-container` elements are fired, you might consider use of jQuery's [.each function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) or use CSS in the selector, as follows

>

```
$('.tooltip-container .tipTrigger').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').prev('.tipText').stop(true, true).fadeToggle('fast'); 
});
```

## For Further Understanding

- [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/): toggle's class active on this element
- [.prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/): moves chain into referencing the element having class `tipText` that comes before current element in dom
- [.stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/): stops any anymation in current on this element
- [.fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/): will begin to fade the element into "hiding"

Comment: SpYk3HH, so let's say I have single JavaScript file with custom scripts, ie:"custom-scripts.js" that gets included in all the pages on the site. By using the `if` statement above when a page reads the custom-script.js file it will only execute the scripts in that file that match the elements in that specific page's DOM. Would it be Ok to do something like this? Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo Yep, but you're still doing a DOM traversal looking for `.tooltip-container` elements (with the `if`), so I'm not convinced it buys you anything. The non-`if` version does the same traversal looking for `.tip-trigger` elements--if there aren't any, it won't do anything either.

Comment: I'll elaborate a bit: The reason I'm thinking of that idea is because I need to keep things simple for our offshore developers, they have quite a hard time following best practices. So by having a single JS file that handles ALL the scripts, they wouldn't have to worry about adding specific scripts to a page, they'd only include that one custom JS file and that's it. Thing is that I don't know if creating all my custom scripts with the `if` statement is such a good idea, AND doing this and creating one single JS file is as well. My gut feeling tells me it isnt but I'd like to know your opinion

Comment: @Ricardo Well including your "custom.js" after the jQuery.js will be the same as writing the js in the webpage.  As Long as jQuery is loaded first.  That if statement, as it stands is no different in performance from the CSS version at the end of my answer.  Javascript and website development is like writing program code for a robot arm. It's read left to right, top to bottom. However, JS can be including at the begining or end of page do to it's functionality. Including all your custom script in one file to be inserted after jQ is good idea...

Comment: However, there are several ways to write every funciton in javascript, it doesn't change the way it proceeds.  In this case, it will still look for elements with those class names.

Comment: Sounds good SpYk3HH. Thanks for your help and information. And thanks to David M and Dave Newton as well.

Answer (score 4):

The second sets the hover function only if there are one or more DOM elements with the class `"tooltip-container"`.

Both traverse the DOM to find elements with the specified class(es); whether or not the difference in efficiency is worth it depends on the DOM, when the statement is called, etc.

Answer (score 4):

1. The hover functionality will only be registered if...
2. ... there is at least one element in the page with class "tooltip-container".
3. Slight performance maybe, unless there is some hidden magic in the way these tooltips work I don't know about.
4. If it's not going to slow it down or error, I generally favour cleaner code over miniscule performance tweaks.